# What happens if I don't receive dynamicLink with getDynamicLink(intent)?

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

According to documentation

> You must call getDynamicLink() in every activity that might be launched by the link, even though the link might be available from the intent using getIntent().getData().

So I already have an deepLink intent handler that every time I receive a dynamic link it gets the deepLink and handles it using intent.data, I know it provides assistance in removing the dynamicLink from memory but aside from that does it improve functionality in any way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDynamicLink()` can be used to validate that the app has been launched by a Dynamic Link, and not through some link that the app's Intent can receive.

It also has a function that can fetch custom parameters added in the deep link. This can be done by calling `pendingDynamicLinkData.link.getQueryParameter(String)` as demonstrated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/rewarded-referral#kotlin+ktx_2).